# How to find a control by ClientID in c# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol, clientid

I'm trying to write a generic function that scours all the form-input controls inside a given parent so that I can repopulate the form's values at a later time.

I store each control's **ID** and **VALUE** in a cookie, and I repopulate the controls by using `FindControl(ID)` to locate the control before setting its VALUE.

All works fine, except in the case where I have multiple instances of a usercontrol, inside which there are child controls.

For example, a DateRange control defines two textboxes...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom"  />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo"  />
```

Then in my form, if I have two DateRange controls...

```
<my:daterange id="DateRangeA" />
<my:daterange id="DateRangeB" />
```

...I now have **2** textboxes whose IDs are both `txtDateFrom` (and 2x`txtDateTo`) thus I'm unable to either store both values in the cookie (as their IDs are not unique) nor retrieve the controls again using `FindControl()`.

What I would like is something similar to `FindControl(ID)`, but using the CLIENTID instead so that I can distinguish between child controls with the same ID inside different usercontrols.

I balk at the idea of having to manually store the complete path to all the controls (somehow), and then using `FindControl(IDa).FindControl(IDb).FindControl(IDc)...` (or whatever) to drill down to the child controls.

There must be a simpler way, right?

Or am I approaching this all wrong?  Advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make your control implement the [INamingContainer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)

According to the article :

> Any control that implements this interface creates a new namespace in
>   which all child control ID attributes are guaranteed to be unique
>   within an entire application.

Also, check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Okay so I tried that, and while the IDs rendered to the HTML elements are now indeed unique, the ID accessible to the code-behind has not changed.  Thanks for your advice.  In the meantime, I have opted for a (hacky) workaround, and store EVERY control by `PARENTID+">"+ID` whether it needs it or not.  Thus the following is enough to consistently locate any control I'm likely to use: `FindControl(PARENTID).FindControl(ID)`